# Making richtextbox bold in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I'm trying to make bold text in richTextBox. Text I want to make bold is in a second row "Cpu usage" in code.

Can you edit this code to make it bold?

`double cpuUsage = Math.Round(perfCpuCount.NextValue(), 2);
 MonitorLog.AppendText(string.Format("Cpu usage: {0}%\r\n\n", cpuUsage));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `SelectionFont` to include the bold style, and write the text that should be bold, then switch it back to regular:

```
MonitorLog.SelectionFont = new Font(MonitorLog.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
MonitorLog.AppendText("CPU Usage:");
MonitorLog.SelectionFont = new Font(MonitorLog.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
MonitorLog.AppendText(string.Format(" {0}%\r\n\n", cpuUsage));
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I needed. So basically, If I want to change fontstyle, font color, etc. I need to select section of text I want to change like in the code, right?

Comment: @Tasas, yes. I haven't done winforms stuff in a while but it may also be worth defining the bold and regular fonts somewhere else instead of creating a new instance every time you need to update the text.

Comment: I thought about making function for font styling. :)